# In gitlab CI is there a way to visualise custom output files

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am migrating from Jenkins CI to gitlab CI. In jenkins I was able to parse some extra output files - for example a `my_results.xml` file which has some lines in XML which we could parse into a custom visualisation like the ones below:

[image]

Note: these are just example visualisations.

My XML might have some simple lines like:

```xml
<summary>
   <warnings>10</warnings>
   <errors>2</errors>
</summary>
```

This would be displayed over time into a graph like in the images above. Is it possible to write a  custom parser / visualiser in gitalb CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing in GitLab as Jenkins plugins.

But you could - for instance - develop a side application that interacts with GitLab through its [APIs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/).

There, you'll be able to do whatever you want. For instance [download Job artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html), store them in a timeseries database, display them in a dashboard.

If the application is a pure web client, it could even be hosted in GitLab pages.

Comment: thanks. I am not sure my question was that clear - I was not looking for jenkins plugins in gitlab, but more a gitlab feature/plugin that could display a custom XML / JSON result file into (for example) a graph over time.  The jenkins reference was just a comparison, I am looking for something in gitlab that is similar to the jenkins feature.

Comment: Right but no, there is no such feature. Indeed that could be nice...

Comment: ah damn - thanks for confirming and put me out of my misery : )